# Why scala does not infer type in partially applied function?

Tags: scala, type-inference, partially-applied-type

Given scala's type inference, I'd expect following not to fail:

```
scala> def partiallyApplied(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) = x + y + z
partiallyApplied: (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int)Int

scala> val partialSum = partiallyApplied(2, 3, _)
<console>:11: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => partiallyApplied(2, 3, x$1))
   val partialSum = partiallyApplied(2, 3, _)
                                           ^
```

And of course, this works:

```
scala> val partialSum = partiallyApplied(2, 3, _:Int)
partialSum: Int => Int = <function1>
```

Is there a reason why type inference does not help with partially applied function in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions) says exactly in which cases parameter types can be omitted and this isn't one of them:

> If the expected type of the anonymous function is of the shape `scala.FunctionN[S1,…,Sn, R]`, or can be SAM-converted to such a function type, the type 
>   `Ti`
>    of a parameter
>   `xi`
>    can be omitted, as far as
>   `Si`
>    is defined in the expected type, and 
>   `Ti = Si`
>    is assumed. Furthermore, the expected type when type checking `e` 
>    is `R`.
>
> **If there is no expected type for the function literal, all formal parameter types `Ti`
>    must be specified explicitly, and the expected type of `e` 
>    is undefined.** The type of the anonymous function is `scala.FunctionN[T1,…,Tn, R]`, where `R` 
>    is the packed type of `e`. `R`  must be equivalent to a type which does not refer to any of the formal parameters `xi`.

Could it be changed to work in this specific case as well? Sure. Is the change worth it? Probably not.